# expand the parents of a node in dynatree

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to find out all the parents in dynatree based on a given node and expand the parents.

```
function Expand(node){
  $(".dynatree-node").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == node){
            node.visitParents( function (node) {
                   node.toggleExpand();
                },true); 
        }
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong?How to proceed?

Answer (score 4):

**node.makeVisible()** will expand the parents

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("..dynatree-node").each(function(){
    var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(this);
     node.getParent().expand(true);     
});
```

Comment: dynatree supports node.expand and this should expand all: $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){
    node.expand(true);
}); But not releated to parents.